# Showing that Each Member of the Cantor Set has a Unique Representation as a Particular Series

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

**Setting:** Recall that the construction of the Cantor Set is $C = \bigcap_{n=0}^{\infty} C_n$ where the $C_n$ are defined as follows:

$$
C_0 = [0,1]
$$

$$
C_1 = [0, \frac{1}{3}] \cup [\frac{2}{3}, 1]
$$

$$\vdots$$

$$
C_n = \frac{C_{n-1}}{3} \cup \left( \frac{2}{3} + \frac{C_{n-1}}{3} \right)
$$

Furthermore, let $X = \{x_i\}$ s.t. $x_i = \sum_{n \ge 1} a_n / 3^n$ where each $a_n$ is either $0$ or $2$.

**Goal:** Show that $X = C$ and that, furthermore, each $x_i \in X$ is *uniquely* associated with some $c \in C$.

**Attempt to Show $X \subseteq C$:**

$\fbox{Showing that $x \in X \implies x \in  C_0$}$

1. Let $x \in X$ so that $x = \sum_{n \ge 1} a_n / 3^n$ for some $\{a_n : a_j = 0 \text{ or } a_j = 2 \text{ for all } j \in \mathbb{N}\}$.
2. First we show that $x \in C_0$.  Then we will show inductively that if $x \in C_k$ then $x \in C_{k+1}$.  It will follow from these two facts that $x \in \bigcap_{n=0}^{\infty} C_n = C$ as desired.
3. Since all of the terms of $\{a_n\}$ are either $0$ or $2$, we have that $\sum_{n \ge 1} a_n / 3^n \ge 0$ and hence $x \in [0, \infty)$.
4. On the other hand, we have that $\sum_{n \ge 1} a_n / 3^n$ can be at most $\sum_{n \ge 1} 2 / 3^n$.  Yet we have from real analysis that

   $$
   \sum_{n \ge 1} 2 / 3^n = 2 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (1/3)^n = 2 \left( \frac{1}{1-1/3} \right) - 2(1/3)^0 = 3 - 2 = 1
   $$

   so that $x$ is at most $1$ and hence $x \in [0,1]$ as desired.

$\fbox{Showing that $x \in C_k \implies x \in  C_{k+1}$}$

1. Fixing the terminology from the inductive hypothesis, suppose now that $\sum_{n \ge 1} a_n / 3^n = x \in C_k$.  We aim to show that $x \in C_{k+1}$ as well.
2. Recall that

   $$
   C_{k+1} = \frac{C_k}{3} \cup \left( \frac{2}{3} + \frac{C_k}{3} \right)
   $$
3. **I'm not sure how to proceed from here...**

Comment: in 4. you have $n\geq1$ not $n\geq0$ so you should do $2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (1/3)^n=\frac{2}{3}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (1/3)^n=\frac{2}{3}\frac{1}{1-1/3}=1.$

Comment: Your approach of showing a bunch of upper and lower bounds for the real number intervals is ok though, maybe try to come up with some inductive argument.

Comment: I made edits above from these comments and made slight progress in my above proof attempt.  I flagged at the end where I'm not sure how to proceed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at the first step by cutting middle part we neglect the numbers that the first digit in their decimal expansions is 1, i.e. if $1/3\leq a\leq2/3$ then one can easily show that $a=0.1a_2a_3...$ such that $a_i\in \lbrace 0, 1, 2\rbrace$.

and at the second step by neglecting the middle section of $[0, 1/3]$ and $[2/3, 1]$ in fact we put away the numbers that their second digits is $1$. in fact if $a\in [1/9, 2/9]$ then $a=0.01a_3a_4....$ and if $a\in [7/9, 8/9]$ then $a=0.21a_3a_4...$ s.t. $a_i\in \lbrace 0,1,2\rbrace$

By following this trend you reach your goal.